# Update SQL post from REACT

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, web, axios

I build a react app using nodejs and mysql. I want to update an entry from react but the following code doesn't working and I can't understan what is the problem. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

// from index.js

```
script.get('/updatepost/:id', (req, res) => {
    let sql = `UPDATE posts SET name = '${req.body.name}', school='${req.body.school}' WHERE id = ${req.params.id}`;
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Post updated...');
    })
});
```

//from react component

```
axios(`http://localhost:4000/updatepost/${userId}`, {
method: 'PATCH',
data: qs.stringify(data);
})
```

Comment: Your router on your server is listening on the `GET` method. Switch to 
`script.patch('/updatepost/:id')`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't working.

Comment: @AlexandruOprescu: post the error details, if any, you are getting. This might help others identify the specific problem you are bumping into